# Why don't third parties in the United States advocate for Approval/Range Voting?

Tags: united-states, voting-systems, third-party

I've been thinking a lot about governance systems and how a certain governance structure may systemically reinforce certain behaviors.
Specifically, it seems [experimentally](https://rangevoting.org/Duverger.html) impossible for third parties to maintain legitimate representation without using a approval/range voting. Can someone explain why third parties & third party advocates aren't pushing for this?

Let's be honest - the Republocrat duopoly sucks for a lot of American citizens. So it seems in every citizen's interest (except for those guaranteed secure positions by the Republocrat duopoly) to push for approval or range voting methods, which can be practically implemented.

Note, that even both [Republicans](https://rangevoting.org/ForReps.html) and [Democrats](https://rangevoting.org/ForDems.html) would have succeeded with range/approval voting methods. Why aren't third parties uniting for their survival?

Comment: What makes you think they aren't pushing for it?

Comment: It's not entirely on not cleanly two-party -- see also [RINO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republican_In_Name_Only), [Blue Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Dog_Coalition), and so on, see also [whip in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_(politics)#United_States).

Comment: What do "third parties" want that they do not already have? To replace the ruling class with their class? Who precisely would "third parties in the United States advocate for Approval/Range Voting" to?

Comment: Maybe this question could be improved by explaining what is (are?) approval/range voting.

Comment: Many third parties are pushing for different voting methods. It seems like Range/Approval voting is really the best option for any third party. 
Range/Approval Voting is explained here: https://rangevoting.org/RangeVoting.html

Comment: "Republocrat duopoly sucks for a lot of American citizens", this sounds like an opinion. As in, how much is a lot? Is it enough that it matters? "Why is a third party not more powerful?" has been answered before.

Comment: To spare the feelings of *politics.SE*'s duopolist users, perhaps this Q. might be phrased less provocatively?

Comment: It might be better to ask why a lot of third parties advocate for Instant-Runoff Voting ("Ranked Choice Voting"), when it doesn't actually help third parties.

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that people don't use it correctly.  We have someone on this site who works on voting machines.  The results that company was seeing were that people were only approving one candidate rather than picking everyone with whom they agreed more than they disagreed.  When that happens, approval voting devolves to first-past-the-post, and obviously if we liked FPTP, we wouldn't want to change voting systems.

Another problem is that approval and range (score) voting don't necessarily pick the best outcome even when used correctly.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_electoral_systems).  They do not comply with either the Condorcet criterion or the later-no-harm criterion.  Contrast with Instant Runoff Voting (which meets later-no-harm) or Ranked Pairs (which meets the Condorcet criterion).

Beyond all that, many third party supporters would prefer to be able to say that they wanted to support their candidate first.  In approval voting, you can't indicate that you prefer your third party candidate to the major party candidate except by leaving the major party candidate off the ballot.  But the whole point is that third party supporters want to support their best candidate while still expressing a preference between the two candidates with legitimate chances to win.

And of course it generally wouldn't make any difference.  In most elections one of the major party candidates would win anyway.  The real goal for many third party supporters is not to change how single candidate elections work but to switch to multiple candidate legislative elections.  Because third parties can win seats in proportional systems like single transferable vote.  And the major parties might break up into more ideologically focused factions.  I.e. the Freedom Caucus and Main Street Partnership might split away from the Republican party.  Same thing with the Social Democrats, the Congressional Black Caucus, and the Blue Dogs among the Democrats.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have more information (e.g. reference/source) on the wrong usage of these voting systems (i.e. the first paragraph)?

Comment: Interesting stuff. Yeah, if voters don't use it correctly, it doesn't matter. 

1) Regarding the Concordet Criterion: https://rangevoting.org/AppCW.html

2) Range voting allows voters to demonstrate the preference of third party candidates to acceptable major party candidates by allowing for a relative rating. I agree approval voting doesn't do this, but its really a special case of range voting.
Edit:
2) We should move to PR legislatures, but PR legislatures shoudn't be party based, but candidate based. In that sense, asset voting seems best for PR: https://rangevoting.org/Asset.html

Comment: @Brythan Later-No-Harm is a terrible criterion which any sensible voting system should hope to violate. It is the inverse of [Monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonicity_criterion) and cannot be achieved without giving up "No Favorite Betrayal" (i.e. voters are strongly incentivized not to mark their ballots honestly).

Comment: Condorcet criterion is only "the best outcome" when you're limited to ranked ballots.  Rated ballots provide more information than ranked ballots, and can find a better winner than the Condorcet winner.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox#Example

Comment: "And of course it generally wouldn't make any difference."  It would make a big difference, electing candidates whose platform is similar to that of the average voter, rather than alternating between polarizing left- and right-wing candidates.

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia:

> Approval voting has been used in privately administered nomination contests by the Independent Party of Oregon ... It is also used in internal elections by the American Solidarity Party, the Green Parties of Texas and Ohio, the Libertarian parties of Texas and Colorado, the US Modern Whig party
>
> Score voting is used by the Green Party of Utah to elect officers, on a 0–9 scale.

So I'm not sure your premise is correct.